# How to import and get variables from another python file?

Tags: python, variables, import

The main file is aaa.py, code as below:

```
import os,time
from get_newest_folder import *

def main_test():
    print(newest_folder)
    print(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_n_folder()
    main_test()
```

The another file is get_newest_folder.py, code as below:

```
import os

def get_n_folder():

    path = 'D:\\Test'    
    os.chdir(path)
    files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=os.path.getmtime)

    newest_folder = files[-1]
    return (path, newest_folder)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_n_folder()
```

I'm trying to use variable "path" and "newest_folder" from get_newest_folder.py in aaa.py, so I import "get_newest_folder". But I can't get(print) the 2 variables in aaa.py. It displays the error message as below when I run aaa.py:

> NameError: name 'newest_folder' is not defined

Does anyone can correct my code or give me some suggestion? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your aaa.py

```
import os,time
from get_newest_folder import *

def main_test():
    path,newest_folder = get_n_folder()
    print(newest_folder)
    print(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to access newest_folder and path, you have to declare them as global in get_newest_folder.py and import these variables in aaa.py. They are local variables currently.

But this is not an ideal way to get about things. May be you need something like this

```
import os,time
from get_newest_folder import *

def main_test():
    _path, _newest_folder = get_n_folder()
    print(_path)
    print(_newest_folder)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_test()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to answer your question, you need to modify your module:

```
import os

newest_folder = ''         # <<<<
path = ''                  # <<<<

def get_n_folder():
    global newest_folder   # <<<<
    global path            # <<<<

    ....
    # The rest is unchanged
```

The variables are attributes of the module now, previously they were only attributes of the function.

So that got rid of the error messages, but it just prints two blank lines!!!  Why?  Because `newest_folder` and `path` have not been setup, you don't call the function to populate the values!

That's one problem, the other is `from get_newest_folder import *`.  Don't do that - it pollutes your own namespace.  It gives the opportunity for a module to overwrite your own variables (namespace collision).  Fine, you know this module, but will you always?  Do you know very variable in every module that you import?

So:

```
import get_newest_folder

def main_test():
    print(get_newest_folder.newest_folder)
    print(get_newest_folder.path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_newest_folder.get_n_folder()
    main_test()
```

But, as others have said, it is better *not* to share variables, if you do it means that the module implementation cannot change - it breaks *encapsulation*.  There are a few occasions where it might be justified, but not here.

Instead, using your *original* `get_newest_folder.py`:

```
import os,time
import get_newest_folder

def main_test():
    print(newest_folder)
    print(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dir())
    newest_folder, path = get_newest_folder.get_n_folder()
    main_test()
```